# undefined variable error in view in laravel mailable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have seached and found so many solutions of this and tried all but the issue is same.

```
class InvoiceMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $user;
    public $payment;
    public $invN;
    public function __construct($user,$payment,$invNum)
    {
        //
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->payment = $paymentt->toArray();
        $this->invN = $invNum;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        return $this->from('hardliftersgym@gmail.com')->view('email.invoice')->with(['user'=>$user])->attach('invoice/'.$this->invN);
    }
}
```

I have tried this

```
public function build()
    {
        $data = array('user'=>$this->user);
        return $this->from('hardliftersgym@gmail.com')->view('invoice',$data)->attach('invoice/'.$this->invN);
    }
```

and this is also not working

```
 return $this->from('hardliftersgym@gmail.com')->view('invoice')->with('user',$this->user)->attach('invoice/'.$this->invN);
```

and

```
return $this->from('hardliftersgym@gmail.com')->view('invoice',compact('user'))->attach('invoice/'.$this->invN);
```

and these are also caught the same error

> Undefined variable: user (View:
>   resources/views/email/invoice.blade.php)

I am  trying to resolve this since morning but I am not getting what is wrong with the code.

Please help.

Comment: Try to log `$this->user` if you actually have the user data

Comment: please edit your question and attach the relevant part of `invoice.blade.php`

Comment: You have another typo error here: $this->payment = $paymentt->toArray(); Double "t"